# foreach to include main project

Tags: git

So I have ended up with a complex operation being done in a `git submodule foreach  --recursive`.

I want to do the same operation for the main module. I don't really want to repeat the complex operation.

Is there some way to get the main module included in the foreach listing?

I can see that one way is to convert the foreach to an output listing, but that is quite messy, though it does have the advantage that I don't have to do a `bash -c 'expression'`:

```
cat <<(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) <<(git submodule foreach --quiet --recursive pwd) | while read i; do cd "$i"; do_my-complex_stuff ; done
```

And, of course I can write a bash script that self-calls as the foreach expression, but I'm not a great fan of libraries of scripts.

Is there a simpler way to get the main project included in the scan, given that it is --recursive already?

Comment: I have found the git command `git ls-files  .  --recurse-submodules` is generally more useful, as it lists all the files relative to the project root, including the main module and all submodules. Makes my script much simpler.